# Java Generic inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement some code that starts with a parent who has a generic variable, and then the child inherits it.

```
public class Parent <A>{
private A a;

public Parent (A a){
    this.a=a;
    }
} 

public class Child <A> extends Parent<A>{

private A a;

public Child (A a){
    this.a=a;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compile error stating

> `constructor Parent in class Parent<A> cannot be applied to given types; A`

Comment: Having two fields both called `a` is going to get really confusing, even though there'll be no code that can access both of them.  I would advise giving the subclass's version of `a` a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly invoke the parent's constructor from the child's constructor:

```java
public class Child <A> extends Parent<A> {
    public Child (A a) {
        super(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you don't need to add the field `a` in the subclass. It's inherited.

Comment: @akuzminykh If `Child` uses `a` then it is going to need it. Typically you'd want to avoid the inheritance. This sort of thing indicates the design is off.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline No, when it's going to need it, you don't need to declare it again. And would you mind to add a reference that explains the *"Typically you'd want to avoid the inheritance."* and *"This sort of thing indicates the design is off."*? I got curious and would like to research that.

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing super(); and obviously that wasn't working.  Thank you for the answer.